# Laravel simple ecommerce logic for picking list

Tags: laravel, eloquent, e-commerce, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

im struggling to create a simple logic.. i have collection of orders… some of the orders have the same products in them.. and with different quantities.. i want to create a picking list of these orders..
for instance..

- Order1 = iphone xs : 1
- Order2 = iphone xs : 2, iphone xs max : 1
- Order3 = iphone xs : 1, iphone xr : 2
- Order4 = iphone xs max : 2

my current code:

```
@php
$x = $allorders->pluck('SKU')->all();
@endphp
@foreach ($x as $z)
    @foreach ($allorders->where('SKU', $z)->pluck('quantity_ordered') as $grouporder)
        {{$z}} : {{$grouporder}} <br>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

the output is like this:

- iphone xs : 1
- iphone xs : 2
- iphone xs : 1
- iphone xs max : 1
- iphone xs max : 2
- iphone xr : 2

Instead how can i show it like this:
so my picking list would show:

- iphone xs : 4
- iphone xs max : 3
- iphone xr : 2

Comment: Can you show us your `products` and `orders` schema? This looks like it can be achieved using `count()` and `groupBy()`

Comment: `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ASIN` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SKU` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `item_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity_ordered` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity_shipped` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` double(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL

Comment: not this way.. I don't need the datatypes, just the columns and how are they connected. Edit your post and add these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select SKU, sum(quantity_ordered), min(title) from product_details group by SKU
```

this worked for me.. thanks :)